# Add custom Jinja2 filters/tests to MkDocs

Tags: jinja2, mkdocs

While writing a Jinja2 template for MkDocs, I need some processing that is not covered by the filters/tests available (specifically, I need date formatting, which is a recurring example for custom filters in Jinja2-related resources across the Web). **How can I define my own filters/tests and use them from templates?**

To clarify the question, I know [how to register new filters/tests in a Jinja2 environment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-filters) *from Python*. My issue is that, *as a user* of MkDocs, I do not configure Jinja2 myself. So what I’m looking for is a way to hook into the setup that MkDocs performs.

I assume it is possible to add filters from a plugin. In fact, I have found [one such plugin](https://github.com/burnedikt/mkdocs-jinja2-filters-plugin) (undocumented and apparently not under active development, unfortunately). However, I hope that there is a simpler, local solution; one that would not involve [implementing a plugin](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/plugins/), packaging it as a Python package and publishing it on PyPi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [mkdocs-simple-hooks](https://github.com/aklajnert/mkdocs-simple-hooks) that allows to implement the hooks without needing to create a plugin. For example in your case:

```yaml
plugins:
  - mkdocs-simple-hooks:
      hooks:
        on_env: "docs.hooks:on_env"
```

**docs/hooks.py**

```py
def on_env(env, config, files, **kwargs): 
    env.filters['my_filter'] = my_filter
    env.tests['my_test'] = my_test
    return env
```

Comment: Wonderful! Now I have access to the full power of plugins, without the trouble of packaging/publishing. I actually prefer using this plugin over `mkdocs-jinja2-filters-plugin`, since it is more general and more flexible (I also need plugin powers for other things).

Comment: @Maëlan If you can improve my post feel free to do so, I am not an expert in mkdocs so I only gave a trivial example and without testing it

Comment: Thanks for the edition, sorry for the trouble. :-)